# How to remove single character lines in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

```
p  
I  
n  
g  

1  
1  
.   
1  
1  
0  
.  
5  
.  
6  
ping 11.110.5.6
```

Type escape sequence to abort.

Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 11.110.5.6, timeout is 2 seconds:

```
!  
!  
!  
!  
!  
1  
Type escape sequence to abort.
```

Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 11.110.5.6, timeout is 2 seconds:

Answer (score 1):

Try `ctrl`+`h` to bring up the Replace window and navigate to the `Mark` tab. Make sure `Bookmark line` and `Regular expression` is selected. Paste `^.{0,1}$` into `find what`. It matches lines containing a single character. Then go to `Search` > `Bookmark` > `Remove Bookmarked Lines`.

Comment: How could you answer such question?

Comment: Sure it's not the best question, but should we not try and be helpful nevertheless?